# List files and sub directories Android

Tags: android

What i want to do is to open a directory through android application and list all the files as well as directories present in that directory. I would also like to retrieve permissions and owner information of each file/directory. This can be achieved in java but how can i do the same in Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `java.io` package has been reimplemented within Android.  You should be able to use the same mechanisms in Android as you do in Java.

```
File f = new File("/your/file/path");
File[] files = f.listFiles();
```